# Capture VS Static variables while debugging in EnvDTE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, envdte

The DTE object provides a way to capture all the variables that are in scope:  **dte.Debugger.CurrentStackFrame.Locals.**

What method can I use to list all the static variables?

Comment: The meaning of `static` varies from language to language. The EnvDTE debugger automation interfaces are designed to be language-agnostic, so they probably won't directly expose this concept. In my experience, as soon you need something that doesn't fit within the narrow box of the automation interfaces, you'll have to switch to using the core interfaces instead.

Comment: I meant C# static (Shared in VB), the kind of variables that are not instance specific.  Most languages support some form of static/non-instance data.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, that part is clear from your question. I was simply pointing out that the concept of `static` is not present in the debugger automation interfaces. In fact, the entire concept of an object model appears to be missing as indicated by [`Expression.Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.expression.type.aspx) property having type `string`.